# App crashing in upgrading targetSdk version

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

Play Store now requires that your app uses API level 28:

> Both new apps and app updates must target at least Android 9 (API level 28).

[Source](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

My app was currently using `targetSdkVersion = 26` with this configuration:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

/**
* Project-wide gradle configuration properties for use by all modules
*/
ext {
    compileSdkVersion               = 28
    targetSdkVersion                = 28
    buildToolsVersion               = "28.0.3"
    googlePlayServicesVersion       = "12.0.1"
    googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "15.0.2"
    supportLibVersion               = "28.0.0"
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to fix this I've changed to this:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion               = 28
    targetSdkVersion                = 28
    buildToolsVersion               = "28.0.3"
    googlePlayServicesVersion       = "12.0.1"
    googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "15.0.2"
    supportLibVersion               = "28.0.0"
}
```

The app seems to run just fine in a device we have here which has Android 6.0, but in other devices like Android 9, the app crashes on the start, throwing the error bellow:

[image: Android print]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting in node terminal? or in terminal from where you are running it?

Comment: @gprathour there is no error in the node terminal

Comment: Try cleaning project and restarting node to run it.

Comment: Are you trying to create an app bundle? Can you share the entire gradle script ? Also make sure you have folders for resources in place.

Comment: @gprathour already did it with `gradlew clean`

Comment: @SusheelTickoo I've updated the question with the full script

Comment: Try doing bundling again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below commands:

```
1. cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd ..

2. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

3. react-native run-android
```

Let me know if still facing same issue